# Computing $\textrm{Aut}_{\mathbb{Q}}(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}))$

Tags: extension-field, automorphism-group

I want to know if what I am doing is right.

I know that if $f$ is an automorphism, so $f(2)=2\implies f(\sqrt{2})^{2}=2.$ So, $f(\sqrt{2})=\pm \sqrt{2}$. In the same way, $f(3)=3\implies f(\sqrt{3})^{2}=3\implies f(\sqrt{3})=\pm \sqrt{3}.$

So, setting

$$f_{1}(\sqrt{2})=\sqrt{2},\;f_{1}(\sqrt{3})=\sqrt{3}\; ; \\
\quad f_{2}(\sqrt{2})=\sqrt{2},\;f_{2}(\sqrt{3})=-\sqrt{3}\; ; \\
\quad f_{3}(\sqrt{2})=-\sqrt{2},\; f_{3}(\sqrt{3})=\sqrt{3}\; ; \\
f_{4}(\sqrt{2})=-\sqrt{2},\;f_{4}(\sqrt{3})=-\sqrt{3};$$

we have $\textrm{Aut}_{\mathbb{Q}}(\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}))=(f_{1},f_{2},f_{3},f_{4})\simeq \Bbb{Z}_{4}.$

Am I right?

Comment: All of your work is correct, but the conclusion is incorrect. The group is $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z^2$.

Comment: $\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$ has two elements of order four.  Which of the $f_i$ have order four?

Comment: @DonThousand do you mean $\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}\times \Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$ ?

Comment: @MateusRocha Yes

Comment: Something is missing: you need to show that you can specify the value at $\sqrt{3}$ when the value at $\sqrt{2}$ is fixed. In other words, you need to show that $\sqrt{3} \notin \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$.

Comment: Thank you all for the help :)